# saving R' raster to netcdf .nc file with keeping CRS information

Tags: r, gis, netcdf, r-raster, rgdal

I am having a problem while converting a raster object as NetCDF (.nc) file, with keeping the CRS information in the output file.

Here is a reproducible code:

```
require(raster)
require(ncdf4)
CurrTemp <- tempfile()
download.file(url = "https://seaice.uni-bremen.de/data/amsre/asi_daygrid_swath/s6250/2003/feb/Antarctic/asi-s6250-20030214-v5.hdf", destfile = CurrTemp, mode = "wb", quiet = T)
r <- raster(CurrTemp)
r <- flip(r,2)
extent(r) <- c(-3950000, 3950000, -3950000, 4350000)
crs(r) <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-70 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs "
r
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 1328, 1264, 1678592  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 6250, 6250  (x, y)
# extent      : -3950000, 3950000, -3950000, 4350000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-70 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs 
# data source : in memory
# names       : layer 
# values      : 0, 100  (min, max)
```

So far the raster object reads well, with CRS information included.

However, when I try to save it as .nc file, R prints "coord. ref. : NA", and the produced file does not contain the CRS information.

```
writeRaster(r, filename = "O:/Ahmed/r001.nc", varname="IceConc",
            overwrite=TRUE, format="CDF",
            xname="Longitude", yname="Latitude")
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 1328, 1264, 1678592  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 6250, 6250  (x, y)
# extent      : -3950000, 3950000, -3950000, 4350000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 
# data source : O:/Ahmed/r001.nc 
# names       : IceConc 
# zvar        : IceConc


raster("O:/Ahmed/r001.nc")
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 1328, 1264, 1678592  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 6250, 6250  (x, y)
# extent      : -3950000, 3950000, -3950000, 4350000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 
# data source : O:/Ahmed/r001.nc 
# names       : IceConc 
# zvar        : IceConc
```

Thanks

Comment: It happens even with the `writeRaster` function's documentation example: `rnc <- writeRaster(r, filename='netCDF.nc', format="CDF", overwrite=TRUE) `